# Get list of types from operation variables

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have an operation and I want to get a list containing its variables and types.

Eg. given the operation

```
query getResource($id: ID!, $title: String) {
  resource(id: $id, title: $title) {
     id
     title
     content
  }
}
```

I want to get something like this

```
[{type: "ID", required: true, name: "id"}, {type: "String", required: false, name: "title"}]
```

Is this easily attainable?

Edit: I guess what I want to do is to go from a `VariableDefinitionNode` to an object containing all the information I want, such as `type`, `defaultValue`, `required`, `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to implement this if you change your schema (assuming you can generate this data on the server into this shape)

```
type Query {
  resource ($id: ID!, $title: String): [Variable]
}

type Variable {
  type: String!
  required: Boolean!
  name: String!
  ...
}
```

This is a very generalised syntax however, returning an array of values like that. If the structure of your resources is known, you would be better off defining that and removing the name parameter as it becomes redundant. (I'm thinking about lookups inside your client-side application)

```
type Query {
  resource ($id: ID!, $title: String): Resource
}

type Resource {
  id: Variable!
  title: Variable
  content: Variable
}

type Variable {
  type: String!
  required: Boolean!
  ...
}
```